# How do I disable Esc-v in bash opening the previous command in an editor?

Tags: bash, readline

This has bothered me for years. I have tried to unbind the key sequence in `.inputrc`, I have set `EDITOR` to true and false,  I have read and reread the bash and readline man pages. I have used ksh instead of bash.

How do I disable the behavior of <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>v</kbd> keyboard sequence?

Comment: `EDITOR` is not a Boolean variable.  It specifies the preferred editor to use.  `KSH`, for example, is going to look at what you set it to and try to decide whether to use the `emacs` or `vi` editors on the command line.  I'm not sure whether `BASH` has the same sort of heuristic.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you're unknowingly using `bash` in its `vi` mode.

In `vi` mode, `bash`, like `vi` has an *insert mode* where you can insert text (and a *replace mode* which is a variation on that) and a *command mode* where you can enter motion or action commands such as `x` to delete a character, `b` to move back one word, etc.

You switch from *insert/replace mode* to *command mode* with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and a few commands such as `i`, `a`, `A`, `s`... can make you enter *insert mode* from *command mode*.

In *command mode*, the `v` command brings up an editor to edit the current line (the `vi` editor had no command bound to `v`, so ksh (on which bash is based) was free to use that for that specific task).

Here, it sounds to me that you're not expecting to be using the `vi` style of key binding. `bash`/`readline`'s default key binding is `emacs`, not `vi`, so I suspect you or your system administrator has introduced some customisation that enables the `vi` mode by default.

It could be by adding a `set -o vi` in `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` wherever the system default customisation file for `bash` is on your system, or `set editing-mode vi` in `/etc/inputrc`.

Or it could be that you have similar settings in your own `~/.bashrc` or `~/.inputrc`.

You'd likely want to change it back to `set -o emacs` in `~/.bashrc` or `set editing-mode emacs` in `~/.inputrc`.

Note that the `emacs` mode has a similar function bound to <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>

If you're expecting to be using the `vi` mode, and you don't want `v` to spawn an editor, then you can assign a widget to `v` other than `edit-and-execute-command` such as:

```
bind -m vi-command '"v": abort'
```

Or to an empty string so it's ignored:

```
bind -m vi-command '"v": ""'
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, bind -m vi-command '"v": ignore' is what I have wanted all of these years.  I use vi a great deal,  and use escape often to get into command mode.  I prefer vi mode in my shell, because I use it for my editing.   I have searched many times for "how to disable"  but never found the exact right place to look.  I even read the bash source code to no avail.  Thank you very much.